# How to programmatically write data to a JSON file and then save it?

Tags: java, android, json

I want to put the following data to my JSON file in Android Studio programmatically:

```
[{
    "title":"Olu4a такси",
    "logo":"Taxi/olu4a.jpg",
    "color":"#FFD916",
    "textcolor":"#000000",
    "number":"7000",
    "bigimage":"Taxi/olu4a_car.jpg",
    "star":"4.0"
},
{
    "title":"Asia Express такси",
    "logo":"Taxi/d.jpg",
    "color":"#E7232D",
    "textcolor":"#ffffff",
    "number":"1616",
    "bigimage":"Taxi/asiaexpress.jpg",
    "star":"3.5"
}]
```

How can it be done?

Example

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(); 

try { 
     obj.put("id", "3"); 
     obj.put("name", "NAME OF STUDENT"); 
     obj.put("year", "3rd"); 
     obj.put("curriculum", "Arts"); 
     obj.put("birthday", "5/5/1993"); 
} catch (JSONException e) { 
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
     e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Comment: There are much better ways how to do this than the others advice you.. use Google Gson (or Jackson or Moshi) library to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just user a FileWriter to save to the ExternalFilesDir for exemple

```
public void save(Context context, String jsonString) throws IOException {
  File rootFolder = context.getExternalFilesDir(null);
  File jsonFile = new File(rootFolder, "file.json");
  FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(jsonFile);
  writer.write(jsonString);
  writer.close();
  //or IOUtils.closeQuietly(writer);
}
```

Comment: You dont understand me. I whant use JSONObject and JSONArray for do this dinamicly. But i dont know how !

Comment: If it is well formed, just pass your String as a parameter to the constructor of the org.json.JSONArray (as you have an array in your example)

Comment: @ILHOMA4IK can you just use the JSONArray class to create the array than add the JSONObject into JSONArray?
Example: JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
object.put("title", "Olu4a такси");
JSONArray values = new JSONArray();
Then do values.put(object);

Comment: @ILHOMA4IK just make sure that you handle the exception.

Comment: oh  ! I understand. How how  save it ?

Comment: public void read() throws IOException, JSONException{ FileReader reader = new FileReader(new File("path_to_file)); BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(reader); StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder(); String line; while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) { data.append(line); } JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data.toString()); System.out.println(jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).get("title")); }

Answer (score 0):

You will usually want to use `JsonWriter` when serializing an object to json format.

If what you are trying to do is just write a file with the specific contents you wrote here, you can use `FileWriter`

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), filename);

FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
writer.append(jsonString);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take JSON Path as input and update your JSONObject with JSPATH so that you have option to put it in place where you want